# Modelling a Jammer with Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, wireless, jammer

Is there a reference or a tutorial to simulate a generic transmitter in Omnet++ that transmits noise on a particular frequency? Basically, it is just a simple jammer that disturb the channel by sending random noise (no MAC layer, no Network layer, nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is the NoiseSource module that does this. It is available since INET 4.2:

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/v4.3.3/src/inet/physicallayer/wireless/noise/NoiseSource.ned

This showcase has more info:

https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/analogmodel/doc/index.html

In order to solve this problem, you need to install Omnet, and install manually Inet by cloning the repository from GitHub: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet.

Comment: Thank you adam, but there is a problem related to the noisesource module: <!> Unknown parameter 'gainFunctionCacheLimit' -- in module (inet::physicallayer::NoiseDimensionalTransmitter) AnalogModelShowcaseNoiseNetwork.noiseSource.transmitter (id=281), during network initialization

Comment: I think it's already fixed in INET master. These are about the same issue:

https://groups.google.com/g/omnetpp/c/8SmgDJOi6zY?pli=1

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/issues/646

Comment: I'm using the last version of both. Probably I need to switch to Oment 4.3 instead to use the 5.6.2?

Comment: The latest should work, but i'm not sure if the INET master works with omnet 5.6.2. Maybe you need omnet pre12 preview version.

note: I edited my previous answer to comfirm that the fix is not yet part of any released INET, it's only in the master branch.